# Return object if no params passed in the method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a class method inside my model that I use as a scope

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
   def self.bar(params)
       if !params['some-param'].blank?
           return Foo.where(....)
       elsif !params['another-param'].blank?
           return Foo.where(....)
       end

       self
   end
end

# so in the controller I do something like this
my_var = Foo.bar(params).another_scope.all
```

which works fine. If I change the code to this though

```
def self.bar(params)
   return self if params.empty?

   if !params['some-param'].blank?
       return Foo.where(....)
   end

   if !params['another-param'].blank?
       return Foo.where(....)
   end
end
```

this throws an error: `undefined method 'another_scope' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: `undefined method 'another_scope' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that `params` are not empty. Both of `params['some-param']` and `params['another-param']` are empty. And your method wouldn't rentrun anything.

It's better:

```
def self.bar(params)
    if params['some-param'].present?
        Foo.where(....)
    elsif params['another-param'].present?
        Foo.where(....)
    end

    self
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def self.bar(params = {})                 # with a default value
  params.delete_if { |_, v| v.blank? }    # Clean up keys with blank values

  if params['some-param']
    Foo.where(....)
  elsif params['another-param']
    Foo.where(....)
  else                 # if some unknown key present in params OR the params are blank
    self
  end
end
```